# Kinetic scrolling gone in Firefox after update to 22.04

Tags: firefox, scrolling, 22.04

After updating from 21.10 to 22.04 I no longer get the kinetic scrolling effect in Firefox that was working fine before. `apz.gtk.kinetic_scroll.enabled` is still `true`.

How do I get it back?

Comment: Does switching to the .deb package help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-in-ubuntu-22-04-jammy/1404401#1404401

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Yes! Worked nicely, thanks. Add it as an answer if you want and I'll accept it. It's a mystery how Ubuntu is going to keep its users when they continuously break their users' customisations on every update. I mean, even basic features are absent and require third party gnome extensions, which break on every release like clockwork. Fascinating strategy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Firefox as a traditional deb packag (without snap) in Ubuntu 22.04 (jammy)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-packag-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22-0)

Comment: Instead of adding a duplicate answer, let's mark this as a duplicate of that question, because the solutions are the same. If you want, you can upvote the helpful answers in that question.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I don't think that's what duplicate question means. When these comments are gone this would just be an unanswered incorrect duplicate. It's allowed to link to an existing answer as an answer though, so no need to duplicate it more than has already been done in these comments.

Comment: I have answered the question so that the link can be found even if the comments are gone.

Comment: i have the very same issue but i already used the raw non-snap version downloaded from mozillas website. version 105. i start it with "MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=1 /home/besitzer/.mozilla/firefox-bin/firefox"
however, instead of scrolling, it just selects text when using the touch screen of my lenovo yoga 7.
since 22.04.... 21.10 worked like a charm.
still use x11, not wayland. its not even installed.
ppa version didnt fix it either, as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is another bug with the snap version of Firefox shipped with Ubuntu 22.04. The workaround is to replace the snap version of Firefox with the apt version, e.g. from the Mozilla Team [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Emozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).

See [How to install Firefox as a traditional deb package (without snap) in Ubuntu 22.04 (jammy)](https://askubuntu.com/a/1404401/124466)  for more details.

Comment: Is the bug reported anywhere?

Comment: This fixes the scrolling issue, but creates new issues like that the connectivity between YouTube and Gnome is now gone meaning I cannot control the playback from my bluetooth headphones (skip songs, play, pause, etc).

Comment: I find myself returning to this answer for the third time. Nothing has changed. Firefox has even added support for two finger back and forwards gestures in the meantime, none of which you get access to in the snap version.