# Precise scrolling & pinch to zoom broken in Firefox on 22.04 after working on 21.10

Tags: firefox, touchpad, wayland, multi-touch, scrolling

How do I enable precise scrolling and pinch to zoom in Firefox? I just put the default installation of the latest LTS on my laptop yesterday, and precise scrolling in Firefox is broken (two finger swiping my touchpad emulates a mouse wheel with discrete steps being scrolled smoothly). Kinetic scrolling and pinch to zoom aren't working either. This isn't an X11 issue as I'm on Wayland and this previously worked on Wayland in 21.10.

I'm on a Dell XPS 15 (7590) and precise & kinetic scrolling currently work perfectly in native apps like Nautilus. Any help would be much appreciated, as this is kind of a deal-breaker for me, even though I would genuinely love to switch to Linux permanently being sick of all the anti-consumer nonsense Microsoft and Apple keep throwing my way.

Kind regards,
Kenny

Comment: See if it's resolved in the same way I got kinetic scrolling back: https://askubuntu.com/a/1404660/428527

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever this happens, it stems from Firefox paradoxically using Xwayland even though it's running on Wayland. I had to put `export MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1` in `~/.profile` to get Firefox to stop being weird. I might have had to do more than that, but I can't remember, as it's been several months since I solved this problem. If you have this problem, simply search Google for ways to force Firefox to use Wayland. You can verify that it's currently not doing so by running `xeyes` and checking if the eyes move while hovering the mouse over a running instance of Firefox, if you're uncertain this is the problem.

Comment: I confirm that on Ubuntu 22.04 running on a 2020 MacBook, your solution of putting `export MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1` in `~/.profile` allows accurate two-finger scrolling. Without this solution, all applications except Firefox scroll fine.